# emoji / character viewer in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, emoji

On Mac, control-command-space will bring up a very useful "character viewer", which is great for quickly inserting emojies (see [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25337?locale=en_GB))

What is the equivalent shortcut for Windows 10?

Comment: Windows has a 'Character Map' or 'charmap.exe'. I'm not aware of a keyboard shortcut, but you can pin it to the Start Menu or to the Taskbar. It also doesn't appear to have emojis.

Comment: The windows character map is similar but because it doesn't contain emojies it's not what I'm after in this case (thanks for pointing out though)

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search reveals that on Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, WinKey + . (period) while you are in a text input pops up an emoji keyboard.

Comment: Typed with the WinKey + . keyboard: ✌

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Pro Version 1709 OS Build 16299.125 and WinKey + . isn't doing anything. Attempted with the cursor in multiple places - gmail, facebook messages page, chrome address bar - but no response

Comment: That's odd. WinVer tells me I am running Windows 10 Professional Version 1709 OS Build 16299.214, which doesn't seem all that different. WinKey + . does nothing if I'm not in a text input field, but if I am, I get this:

Comment: According to some other forum posts I just turned up, apparently, it only works if the keyboard is set to "English (United States)". Something to check?